# how to change the label field at run time in vb6?

Tags: vb6

I use quiz system.so i want to use single form.
so i want to know that how to change questions in single form?

Comment: VB what? - VB6? VB.NET? Please give a little more detail.

Comment: You already have a quiz system?  Or you're writing one?  Where are the questions coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
labelname.Caption = "something"
```